# Having multiple threads perform actions based on a global variable

Tags: python, multithreading, variables, global

I'm attempting to have one thread change a global variable and then have the other threads check that global variable and if it changes, perform some action. I've read through threading python docs but it's all very new to me and I'm not sure what the best options are for what I'm trying to do, or if what I'm doing is silly and there's a better way? This code doesn't change color print statements as I wouldn't expect. (Also, this code has to be in python 2.x for some other modules I'm using in my actual project.) ... maybe I should be using a queue object.

```
import random
import sys
import threading
import time

# Globals
output = None

class Green(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if output == 'green':
                print 'green'
                time.sleep(1)


class Red(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if output == 'red':
                print 'red'
                time.sleep(1)


class Color_Randomizer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        global output
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            colors = ['red', 'green']
            output = random.choice(colors)
            time.sleep(1)


def main():

    green = Green()
    red = Red()
    color_randomizer = Color_Randomizer()

    print 'Starting green'
    green.start()
    print 'Starting red'
    red.start()
    print 'Starting color randomizer'
    color_randomizer.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `return output` - why are you doing that?

Comment: That shouldn't be there, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never changing the global variable `output.`  The variable `output` in ColorRandomizer.run is a local variable that shadows the global.

Insert the line `global output` a the top of the `run` function of Color_Randomizer.

Remove the `return output` statement in Color_Randomizer().  Your `time.sleep` call in the next line is unreachable.  Besides, there is no point in returning a value from a thread because there's no way to use it.

Comment: That got it working, thank you. And I'll look into queues based on @ mpolednik comments.

Comment: I will second all of @mpolednik's remarks.  And add that you should also look into daemon threads and understand issues regarding the orderly shutdown of threaded programs.  In your example the Red and Green threads should be daemons..

Comment: Thanks Paul, really appreciate your help. Reading up on daemons now.

Answer (score 1):

The code is very simple in this case and therefore, many hidden issues aren't seen here. The first one is actually seen: using globals isn't the nicest way overall.

More issues will show up as the code becomes more and more complex. The first one is, if you used more complex global structure, you would have to deal with atomicity of it's modifications.

It makes sense to *communicate* with the threads - using queue is one possibility. You would send the current color and threads that understand how to handle that color responded. That is on par with how you deal with communication in parallel (or concurrent in Python's case) environment.

Imagine the change of color as an event and your thread pool as event handlers. This nicely illustrates the flow: event is emitted and candidates respond. Now, even if you added more event sources (*color generators*) there wouldn't be issues with concurrent access to a single variable. Keeping the order, on the hand, would required some synchronization mechanism.